# Time serie model(find Yule-Walker estimators)

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics

I got the  time serie model $X_t=0.9X_{t-1}+Z_t$ with (Z_t) iid studentt-distributed with 10 degrees of freedom. And then I have to find the Yule-Walker estimators $\hat{\phi}$ and $\hat{\sigma^2}$. I have not seen many examples of this and can't totally understand the definitions in my book.
But I think I have to rewrite the  time serie model to $Z_t=X_t-0.9X_{t-1}$ and then I think I the Yule-Walker equations:
$$\hat{\sigma^2}=\gamma_{n,X}(0)-\hat{\phi}  \gamma_{n,X}(1)$$
$$0=\gamma_{n,X}(1)-\hat{\phi}  \gamma_{n,X}(0)$$
Is that correct and how can I use these equations to find the Yule-Walker estimators? Hope anyone can help?